# Python Convert to date and compare

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two strings like 1352789792.757637 and 1352789919.235815. How to convert them back to time and compare?

Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, I extracted the modified time stamp from a file, passed it over socket. On the other hand received this time stamp as string and now want to convert it back to timestamp for further computation. @Fuzzyfelt

Comment: I am still a beginner though @Fuzzyfelt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming that those seconds are seconds since the epoch. If so, this should work for converting to a `struct_time`:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1352789792.757637)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=6, tm_min=56, tm_sec=32, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=318, tm_isdst=0)
```

However note that the format you got back from the file actually represents seconds, so manipulations like differences, etc. can all be done on those numbers. Depending on what kind of analysis you want to do, that may make it a bit easier (i.e. treat them as `floats` instead of converting to time). Not sure of your use case though, so this may be misguided :)

Comment: @Romaan No problemo, hope it helps :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Good call - IPython does make that a bit more confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

To compare, you can use the timestamps directly.
You just need to do something like this:

```
if float(timestamp1)<float(timestamp2): ...
```

To convert a timestamp in something useful, you can use the time module.

For example:

```
>> import time
>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(float("1352789792.757637"))
'2012-11-13 07:56:32'
```

You can use time.strptime to convert back into a timestamp, preformated date string - see the output of this complex example:

```
>> import time
>> time.mktime(time.strptime(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(float("1352789792.757637"))),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
1352789792.0
```